# Max function with tuple key [Updated]

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand what happened in the following line:

```
print(max([1, -2, 3, -1], key=lambda x:(-abs(x), x), default=0))
```

My understanding is, the lambda will return a tuple for each element in the list [1, -2, 3, -1].

But how can a list be compared with a tuple?

And why the output is 1, instead of 3 ?

I've tried

```
print(max([1, -2, 3, -1], key=(-1, 1), default=0))
```

But it said uple is not callable

---

The key to understand the problem here is the key function used. If it's hard to understand, i recommend you to read [this](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/in-python-you-sort-with-a-tuple) and play with sort rather max (cause sort will give you a informational anwser)

My understanding:
Step 1. the lambda function convert `a = [1, -2, 3, -1]` to a new one `b = [(-1, 1), (-2, -2), (-3, 3), (-1, 1)]` 
Step 2. max/sort will deal with the new list`b`. It will first compare the first element, if it's tied, compare the second
Step3. convert the `sorted(b)` in terms of `a`

Comment: _"And why the output is 1, instead of 3 ?"_ Because it applies `abs(x)` first and then makes it negative, so -1 is greater than -3.

Answer (score 1):

The max function goes through each element of your list and applies the lambda function to determine the value of each item, giving you:

```
[(-1,1), (-2,-2), (-3,3), (-1,-1)]
```

It then runs max, which by default first compares the item at the first index of each tuple. Since the first element is negative in all cases, `-1` is the largest first element, which corresponds to the `1` and `-1` in the original array. Since there's a tie, it then compares the second element giving `(-1,1)` as the largest element in this new array, which corresponds to `1` in the original.

Comment: Yes! I did a little extra work to understand this. So the actual compared list is `[(-1,1), (-2,-2), (-3,3), (-1,-1)]` And when this list is compared, the result will be reflected back to the original list `[1, -2, 3, -1]`

Comment: Yes. Exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

you've used key=lambda x:(-abs(x), x) this means the contrary of max that's why instead of getting the largest possible number it gives you the lowest number. Note if there are the +- same number the one that the max will get always is the positive number since its abs()

```
print(max([1, -2, 3, -1], key=lambda x:(-abs(x), x), default=0))
print(max([1, -2, 3, -1], key=lambda x:(abs(x), x), default=0))
print(max([-2, 3, 4, 5], key=lambda x:(-abs(x), x), default=0))

results:
1
3
-2
```

Comment: since all numbers in the list is considered positive number because of abs()

Comment: _instead of getting the largest possible number it gives you the lowest number_ - I guess you could say it gives the number closest to zero, regardless of sign.

Comment: @Jeppe yes. closest to zero since zero is the lowest possible absolute number